# Will perform, will be performed and are performed

Tags: tense, verbs, formal-language

I have a doubt about the meaning of these sentences. It's actually a sentence for my contract.

> Maintenance and security services **will perform by** our contractors.
>
> Maintenance and security services **will be performed by** our contractors.
>
> Maintenance and security services **are performed by** our contractors.

Which sentence is formal to use in a contract?

Comment: I'm no sure if the first sentence is correct. I prefer the second sentence.

Comment: I also had the same feeling about the first sentence. Thanks

Comment: *Services* are usually *provided* (or perhaps *carried out*), rather than *performed*. But this is just proofreading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oops! Then *will be provided* is best/better.

Comment: Note that "I have a doubt" is strictly Indian English and sounds unnatural to native speakers everywhere else; you might want to rephrase more like "I'm trying to figure out the best tense for this sentence among these three".

Comment: @Nathan: Damn your eyes, sirrah! I was just looking at that and debating with myself whether to unilaterally edit to reflect "standard English" *(I have doubts...)*. I probably won't now - partly because it would invalidate your comment, but also because to native speakers *having doubts* usually implies ***suspicion*** rather than simple ***uncertainty*** or lack of understanding.

Comment: "will be" is definite future.  "are" is definite present.  In the context of contract proposal you might use "are to be performed" which carries the sense that it is not the case now but that it is desired.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Indeed. ;)

Comment: The first sentence is 100% grammatically incorrect: You could say _Our contractors will perform Maintenance and Security services_. Drop the **by**. If the "Maintenance and Security services" is at the start of the sentence then it is a _passive_ statement and so the verb "to be" is required. If you omit the "to be", then the sentence is in _active_ voice, and should start with the Subject (our contractors), who is doing the action.

Comment: I don't think this should be considered off-topic for being a proofreading question. The concern is clearly identified: which verb to choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is not grammatical.

The second sentence is idiomatic (for contracts, especially) — it states the obligation as a virtually certain future event.

The third sentence is not necessarily wrong but isn't quite as good, as it implies that the services are *already* being performed.